# CSS Calc - always achieve '0' or '1'

Tags: css, css-variables, css-calc

I have CSS variable called `--size` which is set with javascript. Its value will be 0 or any whole number.

I wish to create a new CSS variable using the `calc` function. I want the value of this new variable to be either 0 or 1.

- If `--size` = 0 then the new variable = 0
- If `--size` > 0 then the new variable = 1

I can use the below code to achieve this:

```
--new: calc(var(--size)/(var--size))
```

But when `--size` = `0`, this does not work.

Is there a way that I can adjust my calculation to achieve 0 or 1 dependent on the value of the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `min()`

```
--new: min(var(--size)*var(--size)*1000,1)
```

If `size = 0` then the result is `0`. If bigger than `0` or smaller than `0`, multiplied with a big value (and itself) it will get bigger than `1` and will get clamped to `1`

```css
.box {
  --new: min(var(--size)*var(--size)*1000,1);
  
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  margin:5px;
  
  border:calc(var(--new)*5px) solid red; /* either 5px here or 0 */
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--size:2"></div>

<div class="box" style="--size:0"></div>

<div class="box" style="--size:200"></div>

<div class="box" style="--size:-200"></div>

<div class="box" style="--size:-.5"></div>

<div class="box" style="--size:.8"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to convert it using `calc()`, you could use `min()`([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min()))

```
--new: min(--size, 1);
```

This will return the variable or 1, whichever is lower, which should result in `1`/`0`.

(This assumes that `--size` cannot be a fraction between 0-1 or a negative number)